# Gremlin query - how to get vertex properties together with edge metadata

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Let's assume that we have the following model.
[image]

So we have permissions which may have Grants, the connection between a Permission and a Grant is called `hasGrant` and has additional property `Type` which can be either `Allow` or `Deny`. How can I write a query, that returns: `PermissionId`, `GrantId`, `Type` without actually traversing to `Grant` vertex ? I'd like to avoid the traversal as it seems to be very expensive and I just need `Type` and `GrantId` properties (which I can take from the edge).
I've tried sth like:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Permission').has('name','Column_Commit')
.project('name','id','grant')
.by('name')
.by('permissionId')
.by(outE("hasGrant").
       project("id","type").
         by(inV().id()).
         by("type").
       fold())
```

This code unfortunately traverse to `Grant` vertex which results in bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the values you need are on the `edge` you don't need to include the `inV` in the query, you can leave it off. However, and I am not familiar with how CosmosDB is implemented, I can imagine that fetching a lot of edge properties could be where the cost actually is. But, anyway, you could write the query as:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Permission').has('name','Column_Commit')
.project('name','id','grant')
.by('name')
.by('permissionId')
.by(outE("hasGrant").values("type").fold())
```

In general, I am surprised that your original query is causing problems as it seems perfectly reasonable Gremlin. The only issue I could envision, in general, is if any of the starting nodes are supernodes.

**UPDATED 2022-07-01**

An alternative approach is to use the `elementMap` step.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Permission').has('name','Column_Commit')
.project('name','id','grant')
.by('name')
.by('permissionId')
.by(outE("hasGrant").elementMap().fold())
```

Comment: The case is that there are thousands of Grant nodes and the traversal takes time. As I am not interested in any values from those nodes, I'd like to avoid traversing them.

Comment: So does pulling the values from the edge as I suggested above work? In some ways this sounds like a key/value store approach might be a better fit if all you need is to find a vertex and immediately adjacent values.

Comment: Partially, as I still need grantId which I'd like to take from the edge metadata. So in this case, it's 'inV'.
Below is a result of g.V().hasLabel('Permission').has('name','Column_Commit')
.outE('hasGrant')
  {
    "id": "44489a50-c9ed-4020-9859-023f97f93006",
    "label": "hasGrant",
    "type": "edge",
    "inVLabel": "Grant",
    "outVLabel": "Permission",
    "inV": "840f5148-8307-4afc-bdfb-9a71359da962",
    "outV": "753a500c-3f1d-4614-a0e3-34f98f3a0445",
    "properties": {
      "type": "Allow"
    }

Comment: I'm not sure if CosmosDB supports the `elementMap` step, but that would be the other way to get information about an edge, its properties and the adjacent vertices. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, can't I only get  `inV` from metadata ? I just want Ids of the vertices. 

CosmosDb doesn't support `elementMap` unfortunately :(

Comment: There really is no concept of the "metadata" you are looking for in Gremlin. You either have to use `elementMap`, or traverse the edge using `outE().inV()` or `E(id).inV()`

Comment: Sorry for wrong wording, by metadata I mean the output of `g.V().hasLabel('Permission').has('name','Column_Commit').outE("hasGrant")` . It's really strange that I can get all values  but I cannot project/select just a single element/property like `inV`.

Comment: Well, `inV` is not a property really, it's going to fetch the vertex attached to the edge. How efficiently that works is going to depend on the underlying storage implementation etc. In general I would expect it to be efficient but I am not familiar enough withCosmosDB to know what the expectations might be. You can project `inV` if you want to and you will get a vertex object back. From your comment above it looks like Cosmos is returning all the properties and labels. In general a Gremlin Server is configured to just return a reference element but perhaps not in this case.

Comment: How about just doing `inV().id()` ?

Comment: That works, but the problem may be how it's implemented in CosmosDB. This query `g.V().hasLabel('Permission').has('name','Resource_Commit').has('tenantId','0').outE('hasGrant')` takes 200RUs but this one `g.V().hasLabel('Permission').has('name','Resource_Commit').has('tenantId','0').outE('hasGrant').inV().id()` 1200 RUs. So it seems that the latter one is six times (just looking at RUs consumption) less efficient than the first one, and that's a big problem for me. Just to make sure we are on the same page, RUs are an abstraction of system resources such as CPU, IOPS, and memory.